# how to bind complex objects in angular2?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, frontend

I am trying to bind this complex object

This is my model

```
export class something{

public Kids: any = { Kid1: { Name: "", DOB: "", Age: "", Gender: "" }, Kid2: { Name: "", DOB: "", Age: "", Gender: "" } };

}
```

and this is my html

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="model.Kids.Kid1.Name" />
```

this is my component

```
model = new something();
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: It doesn't work , the page just freezes

Comment: Did you check the browser console for errors?

Comment: Yeah it gives some routing errors, which I usually get because of the invalid routes I use, there is no error related to this, is my binding correct? or does it has any syntax errors regarding binding?

Comment: Then it's quite unlikely the problem is related to the code in your question but to the routing.

Comment: Please post you complete index.html. Also, it'll be ideal if you post your folder structure.  At the minimum, I'd like to see how you're bootstrapping AJS2.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `model.` from your binding

This works:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="Kids.Kid1.Name" />
```

You don't need to instantiate the model, all the properties on the component are exposed directly

Comment: Yeah, Got it the input tag just misses a name attribute, Now it fine. Thank you by the way